# Upload to pypitest with twine - fails on repeated tests

Tags: python, upload, pypi, version-numbering, twine

`twine upload dist/* -r pypitest`

This command results in the below error when I repeat an upload with the same version number. I thought that pypitest (e.i. https://test.pypi.org/legacy/) was available exactly to support repeated uploads "until I get it right" - instead it seems to be limiting the uploads to once per version number, just like the official site. That is, I get this error:

> HTTPError: 400 Client Error: This filename has previously been used
>   ...

Am I making the wrong assumptions here?

Answer (score 0):

From https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi:

> PyPI test site … is cleaned on a semi regular basis.

As far as I understand this you can reupload the same files after the test PyPI is cleaned but cannot reupload while the files exist.